# Django ajax request from external javascript file

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, django-csrf

I am trying to make an ajax call from an external javascript file.

ajax.js

```
function ajax() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url : "/ajax_get.html",
            type : "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data : {
                client_response : 'Y',
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
            },
            success : function(json) {
                alert('Working');
            },
            error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
                alert(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
            }    
        });
        alert('Failing');
        return false;
    }, 5000);
}
```

Inclusion in the template

```
<script>    
    ajax();
    {% csrf_token %}
</script>
```

Views.py

```
def ajax_request(request):

    if request.POST.has_key('client_response'):
        x=request.POST['client_response'] 
        response_dict={}                                      
        response_dict.update({'server_response':'working'}) 
        return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(response_dict),  mimetype='application/javascript') 
    else:
        return render_to_response('ajaxexample.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I tried to look it up but the only examples I faced where ajax calls from Forms. What I am trying to achieve is to append the output from the ajax call to the file. The console tells me that there is a syntax error regarding the csrf token inside the script tag.

Answer (score 3):

You've placed the CSRF token on its own inside the script tag in the template: that doesn't make sense, as it's not valid Javascript by itself.

Also, although it's not a syntax error, you've used Django template variable syntax inside the JS file itself, which won't be parsed - so the parameter will be sent as the raw string `"{{ csrf_token }}"`.

However the Django documentation contains full instructions for [using CSRF with Ajax](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/csrf/#ajax), so you should follow those.

Comment: Thank you. The <code>{% csrf_token %}</code> was more a brainless addition to try and solve it the "easy" way.